# CameraX slows down when analyse image

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

I am integrating CameraX into the application. And I need to use ImageAnalysis to process the frames. And as soon as I specify setAnalyzer, even with an empty body of the Analyzer, the camera starts to lag on weak devices. And everything was stable on Camera V1.

```
imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
   .setTargetResolution(screenSize)
   .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
   .setTargetRotation(rotation)
   .build()

cameraExecutor?.let { executor ->
   imageAnalyzer?.setAnalyzer(executor, BoundsAnalyzer(::analyser))
}



private class BoundsAnalyzer(val analyser: (ImageProxy) -> Unit) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
        analyser(image)
        image.close()
    }
}
```

Has anyone come across this and can tell you how to overcome it?

Comment: What is lagging? Your camera preview or image analysis speed? Does it get slower immediately or is it always slow?

Comment: @Orcun The camera preview slows down. FPS of the camera is low immediately.

Comment: Got it. I would check 3 things. 
1) Your executor is `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`
2) you have `previewView.implementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.PERFORMANCE` 
3) Your `analyser(image)` does not have messy memory allocations or memory leak when converting from YUV to RGB for example. 
The last but not the least, make sure `cameraProviderFuture.addListener` to get executor as `ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this.context)`

Comment: You can also clone and run this repo of Basic Camerax app to see if this is still the case. This way you can make sure if the problem is in your implementation or in cameraX and weak device combination maybe. https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/CameraXBasic

Comment: I checked these 3 things and everything is correct

Comment: Have any solution for this problem? I got this problem too in weak devices.